# Assigning each line of a file into each element of an array

Tags: c, arrays, file

I'm quite new to C programming and have just begun studying files. I'm wondering whether it is possible to read a file line by line (including spaces in each line) into an array of size equal to the number of lines in the file. I really have no idea where to start or whether this is even possible so any guidance at all would be much appreciated.

**Example**

A text file in the form of:

```
Computer Programming
Software Engineering
Computer Architecture
```

to be written into array such that:

```c
char array[4];

array[0] = "Computer Programming";
array[1] = "Software Engineering";
array[2] = "Computer Architecture";
```

All I have so far is:

```c
int main()
{
    char array[50];
    bool answer;

    FILE *classes;
    classes = fopen("classnames.txt", "r");

    if(classes == NULL){
        printf("\n ************* ERROR *************\n");
        printf("\n \"classnames.txt\" cannot be opened.\n");
        printf("\n         PROGRAM TERMINATED\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

And next I would like to write each class name into each element of the array.

Comment: please post the declaration of `array`. And the code for reading from the file.

Comment: `I'm wondering whether it is possible...` yes, it is possible, but this is wrong site to find solution

Comment: Assuming `array` is a `char **`, you can use [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).

Comment: The declaration of `array` that you have is for exactly four characters, not three arrays of characters, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just have to declare `array` as `char**` and dynamically allocate as you read each line.  E.g.

```
int MAX_NUM_LINES = 1000;
int MAX_LINE_LEN = 256;

char** array;
malloc(array, MAX_NUM_LINES*sizeof(char*));
fp = fopen(...);

int line_ct = 0;
char line[MAX_LINE_LEN];
while ( fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp) != NULL )
{
   int len = strlen(line);
   malloc(array[line_ct], len * sizeof(char));
   strcpy(array[line_ct], line);
   line_ct++;
}
```

I have not actually tried to compile this code, but something like this will work.  You can also replace `MAX_NUM_LINES` with the actual value by doing a quick runthrough first and counting the lines--that would be preferable probably.

Comment: The `while` loop should be `while ( fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp) != NULL )`. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18796037/3386109) for more.

Comment: @user3386109 Wow, that's a great thread, thanks.  I have indeed gone and edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a possible approach

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char        array[100][100];
    char        line[100];
    size_t      arraySize;
    size_t      count;
    FILE       *file;
    const char *filepath;

    filepath = "<put the file path here>";
    file     = fopen(filepath, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
     {
        perror("fopen()");
        return -1;
     }

    count     = 0;
    arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    while ((fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) && (count < arraySize))
     {
        size_t length;

        length = strlen(line);
        if (line[length] == '\0')
            line[--length] = '\0';
        memcpy(array[count++], line, 1 + length);
     }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```